Calculation of boson number density using Bose-Einstein statistics
I need help with the Bose-Einstein statistics for calculating the boson number density. I am trying to perform the calculations for a given chemical potential, $\mu>0$, and I want to integrate from a zero momentum $p$ to some large value. For each momentum, I have a corresponding dispersion relation $E(p)$, which is not equal to $\sqrt{p^2+m^2}$. With this, the number density of bosons can be obtained as follows:
$$n=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{E(p)-\mu}{kT}\right)-1} \ .$$
Here comes the following physical/numerical problems:

What to do when for some small values of momenta, $E(p)-\mu<0$, and the integrand becomes negative?
What to do when we enter a regime with $E(p)-\mu=0$, which gives us a Bose-Einstein condensate?

Regarding the first problem, I was thinking of equating the integrand to zero once it becomes negative for some momenta. But there is no justification for this action, so I think one cannot do this. Perhaps, one needs to make sure that for each momentum, $E(p)-\mu>0$ to avoid the negative integrand.
Concerning the second problem, I think it is best to ignore this regime for numerical purposes as the number density $N/V$ of a condensate would be simply zero for a large system ($V\gg0$).
